# binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<int,int>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, templates, binary-operators

I am recieving this error where I have

```
std:map<std:string,std::string> data{std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int,int>>(in),std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int,int>> ()};
```

is it that Visual Studio is seeing >> as a binary operator rather than the closing brackets for iterator and pair? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you using a pre c++11 compiler?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  Easy workaround is putting a space between: `> >` instead of `>>`

Comment: `stdistream_iterator` -> `std::istream_iterator`

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and it is c++11

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the `>>` in `std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int,int>>`.  This has to do with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) calling the provided stream's `operator >>` to get the elements from the stream.  There is no `operator >>` for `std::pair` by default so unless you provide one you will get a compiler error.